# It's not possible to mock classes with static methods using jest and ts-jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have two classes that simulate a simple sum operation.

```
import SumProcessor from "./SumProcessor";

class Calculator {

  constructor(private _processor: SumProcessor) { }

  sum(a: number, b: number): number {
    return this._processor.sum(a, b)
  }
}

export default Calculator
```

And the operation processor.

```
class SumProcessor {
  sum(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b
  }

  static log() {
    console.log('houston...')
  }
}

export default SumProcessor
```

I'm tryng to mock the class SumProcessor to write the following unit test using jest+ts-jest.

```
import Calculator from "./Calculator"
import SumProcessor from "./SumProcessor"
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils"

jest.mock('./SumProcessor')

describe('Calculator', () => {

  it('test sum', () => {

    const SomadorMock = <jest.Mock>(SumProcessor)
    SomadorMock.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        sum: () => 2        
      }
    })
    const somador = new SomadorMock()
    const calc = new Calculator(somador)
    expect(calc.sum(1, 1)).toBe(2)
  })
})
```

When the static method is present in class SumProcessor, the mock code const SomadorMock = (SumProcessor) indicates the following compilation error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '() => jest.Mock<any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(values?: object, option
s?: BuildOptions) => SumOperator'.
      Type 'Mock<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'SumOperator...
```

If the static method is removed from SumProcessor class, everything work's fine.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

since you have already mocked the `SumProcessor` class with `jest.mock('./SumProcessor');` you can just add a spy to the method you would like to mock, for an example:
`jest.spyOn(SumProcessor.prototype, 'sum').mockImplementation(() => 2);`

this way your test class would look something like this:

```js
import Calculator from "./Calculator"
import SumProcessor from "./SumProcessor"

jest.mock('./SumProcessor')

describe('Calculator', () => {

  it('test sum', () => {
    jest.spyOn(SumProcessor.prototype, 'sum').mockImplementation(() => 2);

    const somador = new SumProcessor();
    const calc = new Calculator(somador)
    expect(calc.sum(1, 1)).toBe(2)
  })
})
```

much simpler, right?

Comment: Great! And what about mock classes that hasn't a default constructor? How to mock entire class and create new instances from it?

Comment: You mean classes with only static methods? If thats the case you could use the same method, and add spy to the static methods if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Not just with static methods. How to do if I want to mock the Calculator class that doesn't have a default constructor?